# Getting content on a server-folder

Tags: java, http, ftp, port, firewall

I got stuck in a Java-noobie Problem.
I have an app which have to download a specific update file from our Server. Lets say the update-filde is located here: http://updates.myserver.com/updates/productA/.
In this Folder, a specific update-file is located with an variable Name, like productA_01, productB_02 etc etc.

Is there any way to get a list of the update-files located in the specific update-folder?

I got this Problem solved using a FTP with listNames(), but we got Troubles with blocked ports from some Firewalls, so sometimes the download did not get to work.

Sorry for my english. Please do not hesitate to ask all questions if my Information was not detailed enough. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 3rd party supports [WEBDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) you should be able to use PROFIND to get the directory contents.
[Sardine](https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine) is a java implementation and the very first example on the readme is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will mark this as correct answer, because the example you posted is exactly what I'am loooking for. However, I have to check if we can do that WEBDAV, not sure at the moment. Thinking about the issue I was wondering if I can get the folders and contents via PHP using a java-php-bridge. Or, my 2nd thought was to set an .txt/xml file with full content, download this one and get the filenames from this txt/xml-file. I dont like this option, because we have to maintain the txt/xml file to get proper function... Any other ideas or thoughts about my ideas?